# Cordova ActionSheet plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use the ActionSheet plugin found at
https://github.com/acyl/phonegap-plugins-1

following the setup instructions:

Using this plugin requires Cordova iOS.

```
Make sure your Xcode project has been updated for Cordova
Drag and drop the ActionSheet folder from Finder to your Plugins folder in XCode, using         "Create groups for any added folders"
Add the .js files to your www folder on disk, and add reference(s) to the .js files using
Add new entry with key ActionSheet and value ActionSheet to Plugins in     Cordova.plist/Cordova.plist
```

i'm not sure about the last step but i found HelloCordova-Info.plist and added an entry there.

compiling fails:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:CompileC build/HelloCordova.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloCordova.build/Objects-normal/i386/ActionSheet-2887A8A627033B74.o /Users/Anthony/dev/phonegap_plugins/phonegap-plugins-1-master/iOS/ActionSheet/ActionSheet.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
Ld build/emulator/HelloCordova.app/HelloCordova normal i386
GenerateDSYMFile build/emulator/HelloCordova.app.dSYM build/emulator/HelloCordova.app/HelloCordova
```

(3 failures)

Comment: i have tried https://github.com/etiennea/cordova-actionsheet but windows.plugins is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one, I just created it yesterday for iOS and it works nicely: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-actionsheet

[image: The Cordova ActionSheet plugin in action]

Comment: THREAD WARNING: ['ActionSheet'] took '16.089111' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.

What is this about?

Comment: It's a warning of iOS, nothing to worry about. It indicates your view may slow down because of heavy processing done on the foreground thread. Showing the actionsheet is a tough operation, but I think you'll agree it works pretty smoothly as is.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same warning. My point is we should give some importance to iOS warnings as much as possible to improve efficiency. Below is the code to fix the warning mentioned,

```
THREAD WARNING: ['ActionSheet'] took '16.089111' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

Fix in code - Objective C:

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Place where you need to display action sheet. 
        [actionSheet showInView:self.webView.superview];
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I changed something similar a month ago, see this changeset: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-actionsheet/commit/1024af59fca7d3191707eb4c63dfd9394dac0961#diff-8d2967e15e7e51bf906ba5dc322e9ec3 .. have you tested the latest version?

Comment: @EddyVerbruggen Thats great, I appreciate. No, I am not using the latest version. Thanks for the notification.